# get the year value in MonthCalendar using C#

Tags: c#, monthcalendar

I have a MonthCalendar in my Form. what i want to do is get the year value when I pick a date in the MonthCalendar.

example:
when i pick 12/01/2021. i want to get the year value like "21" in 2021.
below is my sample code:

```
private void calendar_DateChanged(object sender, DateRangeEventArgs e)
{
    string datepick = calendar.SelectionRange.Start.ToShortDateString();
}
```

thanks in advance. I'm using c# in virtual studio btw.

Comment: Can you show us some code, Where you are storing the date value, and what is the type of that variable

Comment: i edit the question.

Comment: You want to get the two last digit of the year value?

Comment: yes. so i can put it into a variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var Out = monthcalender1.SelectionRange
                        .Start
                        .ToString("yyyy");
```

Your result will be `"2021"`.

Or if you want only `"21"` then try this:

```
var Out = monthcalender1.SelectionRange
                        .Start
                        .ToString("yy");
```